# Get a list of all Gmail conversations with one person across several e-mail addresses

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, gmail-search

Say there's a person in my contact list that uses several email addresses - e.g., john.doe@gmail.com and john@doe.com

I list both addresses in his card at Gmail's contacts, but if I want to get a list of all our conversations, I have to:

1. switch to Contacts
2. search for his card
3. click 'list all conversations'

That works fine, but that's a bit too long.

If I type his name in search box or chat box, I can only select one of his addresses, not both.

In the past I solved this problem by creating a filter and applying a label. However, now I have several people like this, so creating labels for each of them is a bit too much.

So, it there a quicker way to list conversations from all email addresses of a single person?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Gmail search options. In the search box, ask for something like:

```
from:(firstmailaddress@gmail.com OR secondmailadress@gmail.com)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get when I do the three steps above.

I was hoping for a shortcut from a person's name to the construction you gave.
It's a bit cumbersome even for two addresses, and some people use three or four.

Comment: Why not save the resulting URL in your Gmail quicklinks or even in the NOtes section of their contact?

Comment: Thought about it as well. It's pretty much the same as having a label - works fine, but as I got more people like this, I started hoping for a more generic solution :)